# How to programmatically configure keycloak with spring cloud gateway api?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am building one spring cloud gateway and in that I am implementing Keycloak Security everything works fine but need to do programmatically instead of writing in yml file there can be multiple Realms.

Below are the dependencies which I am using:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And my application Api gateway start application code is as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com", "com.b","com.auth","com.security"})
public class APIGatewayApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(APIGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
   @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new PathBasedKeycloakConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

Security Config http code is as below:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain (ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login(); // to redirect to oauth2 login page.

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

and in my application.yml file I am adding below configuration:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          my-keycloak-provider:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8280/auth/realms/Default
        registration:
          keycloak-spring-gateway-client:
            provider: my-keycloak-provider
            client-id: Default
            client-secret: 8ZRUH62Pfhfde6uqasD8dfgdhvqWt03K6
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/app'
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  application:
    name: app
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
```

So we can in configuration file I am manually adding configs for one Realms but there can be multiple realms in that how to do it programmatically dynamic? .

Comment: This does not answer your question, but, in my opinion, an API gateway in OAuth2 ecosystem is a resource-server. An OAuth2 request to a secured resource should be authorized: the clients should have positioned an Authorization header with a Bearer access-token already. Use a [certified OpenID client lib](https://openid.net/developers/certified/) in your clients and send already authorized requests to your API, things will be easier.

Comment: Otherwise, in your conf, write a `provider` for each Keycloak realm and matching clients.

Comment: @ch4mp, Yes that make sense but our application is fully SaaS based so the client won't have direct access to anything, users and realms everything will be created on the fly, so to generate access-token right now they won't have any information. And to create new provider we have to restart server every time that we don't want to do it.